# How to use Groupby function to find a moving average?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, group-by

So I have a CSV file with minute stock data. Though I am looking to find the 20 day moving average rather than the 20 period moving average. So I am trying to use groupby inorder to group the data into day data. But then I am finding issues when I using the .rolling function. The code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
ticker = 'MSFT'
df = pd.read_csv('/Volumes/Seagate Portable/S&P 500 List/{}.txt'.format(ticker))
df.columns = ['Extra', 'Dates', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
df.Dates = pd.to_datetime(df.Dates)
df.set_index('Dates', inplace=True)
df = df.between_time('9:30', '16:00')
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).rolling(window=20).mean()
df.drop(['Extra', 'Open', 'High', 'Volume', 'Low'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Though I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'BinGrouper' object has no attribute '_groupings'`
My hope is the output looks like:

```
                     Close  MA MSFT
Dates       
2020-01-02 09:30:00 158.610 158.91601
2020-01-02 09:31:00 158.380 158.88851
2020-01-02 09:32:00 158.620 158.87451
2020-01-02 09:33:00 158.692 158.85911
2020-01-02 09:34:00 158.910 158.85411
```

But rather than the 20 minute moving average, the 20 day moving average. Though I am also trying to do it where the minute data remains unchanged so that MA MSFT will have the same value for a days worth of data then change for the following day and so on. So for the example above say that the 20 moving average was 158 then it would look like:

```
                     Close  MA MSFT
Dates       
2020-01-02 09:30:00 158.610 158
2020-01-02 09:31:00 158.380 158
2020-01-02 09:32:00 158.620 158
2020-01-02 09:33:00 158.692 158
2020-01-02 09:34:00 158.910 158
```

Then the next days worth of day data would be (if the MA was 159):

```
                   Close    MA MSFT
Dates       
2020-01-03 09:30:00 158.610 159
2020-01-03 09:31:00 158.380 159
2020-01-03 09:32:00 158.620 159
2020-01-03 09:33:00 158.692 159
2020-01-03 09:34:00 158.910 159
```

Comment: `df.rolling('20D').mean()`.

Comment: this gives me the error `ValueError: window must be an integer`

Comment: You might need to upgrade pandas. See [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

Comment: I upgraded to the latest pandas in pip yesterday.

Comment: Also so I tried a lower case d and I didnt get any errors, but the output is chaning. Is that still a 20 day moving average? Or is there a way to just take it of the close of the day?

Comment: The error `ValueError: window must be an integer` means that you are trying to take the average of English sentence (aka "`strings`"). Note that `28.1` might ***LOOK*** like a number. However, `28.1` is probably a text-string under-the-hood.

Comment: Imagine a sheet of graph paper. Each box can contain only one number. What is a "string"? Well, a text-string is like a whole row of graph paper. A ***string*** is a whole row of boxes. Each box in a string (row) contains exactly one letter (a, b, c,...). It is not just letters. A square of graph paper can contain a `$`, a `,` a semi-colon, pound-sign (`#`) etc....  A string is like several hotel rooms next to each-other.

Comment: What is a ***number*** in a computer? A number is one hotel-room only. A number is ***only*** one square of graph paper. A string is ***NOT*** a number. In fact the English string "`2`" is usually the number "`50`" inside of one hotel room. Under-the-hood, the English "`28.1`" is like 4 consecutive hotel rooms, right next to eachother. string "`28.1`"  is the list of numbers `[50, 56, 46, 49]`. In case you are curious, a period/dot "`.`" is the number 46. Thus, `28.198`"  is a whole string of numbers, not just one number. `"28.1"  = ["2", "8", ".", "1"]` which is actually `[50, 56, 46, 49]`

Comment: Anyway, you cannot add, multiply, or divide strings. You can only add, do math on numbers. Numbers are called "floats" and "integers". floats are decimal numbers, like `34.6981`. "integers" are whole numbers such as `+6` or `-927`